# Apache Solr as background process in Windows

Tags: apache, process, background, solr

I would like to run Apache Solr in windows as background Process. Now I am starting solr through terminal using command java -jar start.jar. The problem with this is this stops when the terminal closes..

Any Suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solr with Tomcat.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

As for previous answer, you can do it easier using services.msc to set Tomcat to start on bootup.

---

My answer to a previous question. But this is for setting up multiple "cores", so please dont confuse yourself over this.
[How to start and Stop SOLR from A user created windows service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188816/how-to-start-and-stop-solr-from-a-user-created-windows-service/7203038#7203038)

Comment: +1 We used that method a little while ago on a WinXP VPC (hosted in Windows 7), worked fine - after some fiddling with the configs.

Answer (score 1):

I used this tutorial and it works perfectly:

[Setup Apache Solr on Windows with Jetty Running as a Service via NSSM](http://beckelman.net/post/2011/02/22/Setup-Apache-Solr-on-Windows-with-Jetty-Running-as-a-Service-via-NSSM.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Tomcat as you application host, you can easily run that as a Windows Service. 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html